# tc (netem) - reported loss is different to set loss

Tags: udp, voip, packet-loss

I'm doing some testing on some links, bench marking and I'm using the tc command to simulate packet loss across WANs.
What I have found is that after issuing the command to drop 15% of packets, the reported packet loss is different for different streams within my VoIP analysis.

The setup is simple, two clients attached to a server through a L2 switch. minimal packet loss normally only around 50 machines to this switch.

I'm looking for factors which have made this so, are there facets of the 'tc' command I am not familiar with?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBzxH.png [ss of packet loss]

[edit]
The 26.1% is loss I caused, it is the other two I am curious about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that wireshark was causing my problem, when a VoIP stream changed to, say the hold music, the stream was switched to the hold music from the server, and when the user was taken off hold the sequence numbers had jumped a few hundred making wireshark think there was packet loss.